# why my tabpagenr always returns 1

Tags: vim

I have this loop in my .vimrc to display the tab title as "1: File1.txt" or "2: File2.tx", etc, but both tabpagenr('$') and tabpagenr() always returns 1 no matter how many tabs I open. What am I doing wrong?

```
for t in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    if (t + 1) == tabpagenr()
       let &titlestring = t + 1 . ': '
    endif
endfor

let &titlestring .= expand("%:M")
    if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
        set title
endif
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what's going on?  What is displayed if you just do `:echo tabpagenr('$')` from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it a gain on command line. It gives 1

Comment: How many tabs have you got open?

Comment: I have more than 10 tabs. I closed them all and reopen. Still always 1

Comment: Weird!  Maybe try starting a new `vim` with no `vimrc` using `$ vim -u /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some bits missing from your sample code: how do you expect to change your tab labels with only those few lines?

Anyway, without an argument, `tabpagenr()` returns the number of the *current* tab. Since you are always in the same tab during your loop, that function always returns the same number.

`:help setting-tabline` has an example, did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us on which events your code is executed. If you plainly put this in your `~/.vimrc`, it will only be executed **once** during Vim startup. You need to use `:autocmd` to update the `'titlestring'`, at least on every tab page change (i.e. the `TabEnter` event), or better use an expression in the option to have it continuously evaluated:

```
:set titlestring=%{tabpagenr()}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion in my .vimrc:

"display only file name on tab title
     let &titlestring = %{tabpagenr()}
     let &titlestring .= ':'                                                                                                                                                                  
     let &titlestring .= expand("%:M")
     set title

and got this error:
Error detected while processing /home/viet.pham/.vimrc:
line   44:
E15: Invalid expression: %{tabpagenr()}
E15: Invalid expression: %{tabpagenr()}
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: You're missing the quoting when you use `:let`: `let &titlestring = '%{tabpagenr()}'`.